# How to get Operator Name for SIM in slave slot?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

For dual SIM device how to getNetworkOperatorName which is in slave slot. And my master SIM is deactivated.

Comment: did you found a solution for that, that you can share with us?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find anything on android API to get all SIM operators details.
Only we can get the name of the Current Network Operator or SIM operator

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

SIM operator can be retrieved by using:

```
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SubscriptionManager`'s `getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()

However, keep in mind that it was only added in API Level 22